# Reading MongoDB oplog with Java/Groovy

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

This question has been bounced around a bit, and I promise I have done my best to use previous answers :)

Using the Mongo shell I am able to use find and see all the documents in the oplog.   However if I try to access via java using find() it comes back null.  I even simply tried to use count() and it returns 0.

```
//this does indeed return oplog.rs as a valid collection
def collections = db.getCollectionNames();
println(collections);

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("opslog.rs")

DBCursor cursor = coll.find();

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
println("something here" + cursor.next())
}
```

Seems to return nothing. Or if I just try to print out the cursor I get: **Cursor id=0, ns=local.opslog.rs, query={ }, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary**
I run the same code on another collection and it works.  Do I have to treat the oplog differently in java/Groovy?   Any Java examples would be great if available.

**BTW - I tried to access the other 2 collections in 'local' , system.replset and startup_log and was able to get data back.

Thanks, apologies in advance if I have missed this answer in my search.

Comment: I am not sure if you can access the `local` database remotely. You can try to use the local db. But I'd assume that the oplog (which is kind of important) is basically banned to be accessed from remote clients which aren't a mongo administrative shell.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  That makes sense, I tried moving the script locally but I got the same result.  But maybe you meant oplog could not be accessed anywhere outside the shell??   I feel like I have seen others doing it here (on stack overflow..).

Comment: Actually, it *should* be possible. Fix the typo @helmy suggested (don't forget to give kudos) and try again selecting the `local` database explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, `opslog.rs` should be `oplog.rs`.